# Why this gives 0?

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis

**fixed in 10.0.2.**

Why this gives 0? I am in shock, it should be Sinh[x].

```
FullSimplify[I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[Cosh[t],t,w]/w,w,x]]
```

Comment: @blochwave what returns the whole expression?

Comment: Can you explain why the result should be sinh(x)? Lets assume all is perfect, and so `InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[Cosh[t]]]` should in theory return back `Cosh[t]`, right?   (inverse(fourier(foo))) is foo.  Then why is `I*Cosh[h]=Sinh[x]`? Where did this come from?

Comment: @Nasser did u notice the /w? It should return integral of Cosh[x].

Comment: I did not notice the /w. But still, I do not see how it the final result should be `Sinh[x]`. I think the 0 is not correct and I know why it does it, but I do not see how you came up with `Sinh[x]` either. But not important. I think 0 is not correct.

Comment: @Nasser you can try other functions and see that it returns integral (antiderivative), always.

Comment: @Nasser the power of w gives the order of the differintegral to which the initial funtion will be subjected. If the power is -1, the result should be antiderivative of the initial function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in V 10.0.2. It no longer returns 0. On windows 7, 64 bit:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullSimplify[I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[Cosh[t], t, w]/w, w, x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you are involved the fixing this bug, please consider employing more general methods of Fourier transform, so to get sinh(x) here, because the whole expression should return integral of the function to which it is applied. (and in general, the function's derivative of the order of the power of $(-i w)$. In this case it is -1: $ (-i w)^{-1}= i w^{-1}$, the $i$ is moved to the front of the expression. If you insert normal cosine instead, it will return sine.

Answer (score 10):

As was noted by @DumpsterDoofus, the FT of cosh(x) does not exist. So in a sense this is GIGO. Whether `FourierTransform` should be able to detect this nonexistence is a question I will raise in house.

So why does one get 0 for that transform? I have not checked in detail but will hazaed a guess that `Integrate` (called by `FourierTransform` under the hood) is dropping a divergent part of a result found via Slater convolution, and coming up with 0. Is this wrong? Possibly not. Here is a regularization for the exponential that converges, and from which a limit can be extracted.

```
ii =  Integrate[Exp[-m*x^2 + x + I*x*t], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {m > 0, Element[t, Reals]}]

(* Out[18]= (E^(-((-I + t)^2/(4 m))) Sqrt[\[Pi]])/Sqrt[m] *)
```

`Limit` cannot handle the case of arbitrary real `t` so I'll pick a specific value.

```
In[19]:= Limit[ii /. t -> 7/3, m -> 0]

(* Out[19]= 0 *)
```

So I don't think anything is really amiss, other than possibly that `FourierTransform` does not recognize this nonexistence.

Answer (score 6):

It is not hard to see where the 0 is coming from. It has to do with the FourierTransform part. By the time we get to the Inverse, it is too late. The damage has been done.

```
f = TrigToExp[Cosh[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f1 = FourierTransform[f, t, w]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now Mathematica decided to give zero for each part of the above:

```
FourierTransform[(1/2) ExpToTrig[Exp[-t]], t, w]
(* 0 *)

FourierTransform[(1/2) ExpToTrig[Exp[t]], t, w]
(* 0 *)
```

What this means, is that Mathematica thinks that `FourierTransform[Cosh[t], t, w]` is zero. And `zero/w` is zero. So the division by `w` here makes no difference.

The `InverseTransform` of zero is zero. So the final result is zero.

Now why does M think `FourierTransform[(1/2) E^-t, t, w]` is zero? That is the main question.

`Exp[t]` is 2 sided exponential. Only way to get convergence is like this (from definition itself, but must use `|t|`) else it will not converge.

```
Assuming[w > 0, Integrate[Exp[-Abs@t] Exp[-I w t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: FullSimplify[FourierTransform[(1/2) E^-t, t, w]] does not give zero to me

Comment: @Anixx that is correct, that is why I used ExpToTrig to make it generate a result. Ofcourse `Exp[t]` and `ExpToTrig[Exp[t]]` are the same thing, mathematically speaking. But one gives a result and one does not. That is why. Just to see the zero come out. Else will not see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment.

In MMA10.0.1 on Win7,

```
FullSimplify[I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[Cosh[t],t,w]/w,w,x]]
```

returns `0` as you state.

```
FourierTransform[Cosh[t], t, w]
(* returns FourierTransform[Cosh[t], t, w] *)

FourierTransform[Sinh[t], t, w]
(* returns FourierTransform[Sinh[t], t, w] *)

FourierTransform[Tanh[t], t, w] 
(* returns I Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Csch[(\[Pi] w)/2] *)
```

You can then go to [Wolfram|Alpha's Fourier Transform calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+calculator) and try the same thing.

For example, for `Sinh[t]` W|A tells us:

> (no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)

Comment: ... and so what?

Comment: @blochwave: Thanks for taking the time to provide help. I think what Anixx is trying to say is that `FourierTransform` and `InverseFourierTransform` violate the usual laws of integration and differentiation in reciprocal space when applied to hyperbolic trigonometric functions, and this doesn't really address why that isn't happening correctly in Mathematica.

Comment: I'm trying to show (by way of an extended comment) some more information on the behaviour of what you're trying to do. Since MMA cannot deal with the inner part of your expression, why would it be able to deal with the whole thing? I've then turned to W|A for a bit more information, and `(no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)` is probably why it's not working.

Comment: I honestly don't know why it isn't working correctly, but I'd hazard a guess that it has to do with the fact that hyperbolic trig functions are not elements of the Schwartz space $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and the Fourier integrals are formally divergent. Still, it seems odd that `FullSimplify` would return 0, since typically `FullSimplify` returns the unevaluated expression when it is unable to find a simplified result. That in itself seems like a bug.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus by the way, Simplify also returns 0.